# SASS: use material variables (from angular2)

Tags: css, sass

In material theme there is such code:

```
$md-indigo: (
  50: #e8eaf6,
  100: #c5cae9,
  200: #9fa8da,
  300: #7986cb,
  400: #5c6bc0,
  500: #3f51b5,
  ...
)
```

and

```
.text-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

how in other file i can use this variables (skip import rule)?

for example:

```
.someclass {
    color: $md-indigo-500;
    .text-overflow();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.text-overflow` in `.someclass` as

```
.someclass {
    color: $md-indigo-500;
    @extend .text-overflow;
}
```

Comment: So, for clarity, you'd use `@extend` when it's a class and would use `text-overflow()` if it was a mixin?

Comment: `@include` for mixin. Eg:`@mixin name {
  font-size: 12px;
}

p {
  @include name;
}`